# React functional component re-renders with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am confused about something related to using functional components with React.

Here is my component, the implementation details are not all that important:

```
const Trending = ({ match, actions, trendingPlaces, meConfig }) => {

  const [GeoView, setGeoView] = useState(AcceptCurrentLocationPlaceholder);
  const menuItem = match.params[0];

  console.log('*** Trending ***');

  if (runsOnClient()) {
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('effect is run');
      if (!requiresGeolocation(menuItem)) return;

      if (meConfig.isCustomLocationSet) {
        setGeoView(
          getComponentForMenuItem(menuItem));
        return;

      }

      if (geolocationServiceIsAvailable()) {
        const getCurrentLocation = async () => {
          try {
            setGeoView(AcceptCurrentLocationPlaceholder);

            const currentPosition = await getCurrentPosition(
              getConfig().googleMaps.currentPositionOptions);

            setGeoView(getComponentForMenuItem(menuItem));

          } catch (err) {
            setGeoView(DeniedCurrentLocationPlaceholder);
          }
        };

        getCurrentLocation();

      } else {
          // Display the view mentioning 'geolocation is not available' and set custom location
      }
    }, [menuItem]);
  }

  // Fetch trending places
  const { fetchTrendingPlaces } = actions;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTrendingPlaces();
  }, []);

  return (
    <section id="zp-trending">
      <TrendingMenu match={ match } />
      <div id="zp-trending-body">
        <Route path={'/trending/list'} component={ GeoView } />
        <Route path={'/trending/map'} component={ GeoView } />
        <Route path={'/trending/settings'} component={ TrendingSettings } />
      </div>
    </section>
  );

};


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    meConfig: state.meConfig,
    trendingPlaces: state.trendingPlaces
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(fetchTrendingPlaces, dispatch)
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Trending);
```

When I check my logs, it appears that `*** Trending ***` gets called a bit inconsistently. It would appear that it gets called after every Redux update as well.

Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `bindActionCreators` always returns a new object or function. So you get new `actions` on every redux update.

If you want to keep the nested structure you could do the following

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  const actions = bindActionCreators(fetchTrendingPlaces, dispatch);
  return () => ({actions})
};
```

Or you could flatten the properties so it would pass shallow equality check.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchTrendingPlaces
}; // pass object to connect

// use in component
const Trending = ({fetchTrendingPlaces /* the rest of your props*/}) => {
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tip, but it really didn't change anything. I found what the problem was, will post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Read the react hooks rules](https://ru.react.js.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

### Only Call Hooks at the Top Level

Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls. (If you’re curious, we’ll explain this in depth below.)

### Only Call Hooks from React Functions

Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:

✅ Call Hooks from React function components.

✅ Call Hooks from custom Hooks (we’ll learn about them on the next page).
By following this rule, you ensure that all stateful logic in a component is clearly visible from its source code.

here is the part of your code that breaks the rules

```
if (runsOnClient()) {
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log('effect is run');
      if (!requiresGeolocation(menuItem)) return;

      if (meConfig.isCustomLocationSet) {
        setGeoView(
          getComponentForMenuItem(menuItem));
        return;

      }
```

Fix may help.

Comment: Uhm  ok, but then how do you fix this for a universal component? It's supposed to execute this effect on the client only. I'm also not certain that this is the cause of the problem. console.trace seems to suggest Redux to be the source of the problem.

Comment: I ran the condition inside the effect, but it results in the same issue... btw, the component renders fine...

Comment: @Trace  It's a little problematic to understand your code. Can add your code to codesandbox ?.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I'm using `useState` here which triggers a re-render.

The other re-renders were triggered from:

- The useEffect that requests the trending items, but this is normal as I want them on initial render.
- The match property that is passed for react-router. This is also intentional as the component is re-rendered when the url changes.

Actually within useEffect it seems that I have to use useState to get the conditional rendering. So I guess that the behaviour is as expected.
The UI behaves as expected so I guess that the re-renders are necessary.